# Nanoscroller takes into count the height of hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I'm using nanoscroller, and it doesn't work properly.

This is the code inside the scroll.

```
 <div class="dish">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="title">заливное из языка</div>
    <div class="add"></div>
    <div class="dish-info">
        <div class="info-left">
            <div class="dish-thumbnail">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="images/dish-pic.png" />
                <div class="dish-time">
                    <span class="time">25</span> <span class="minutes">мин</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dish-information">
                <h1>ингридиенты</h1>
                <p>700 г филе индейки</p>
                <p>1 лукавица репчатого лука</p>
                <p>1 морковь</p>
                <p>200 г риса «Арборио»</p>
                <p>1/2 л воды</p>
                <p>50 мл сливок 20%</p>
                <p>200 г брокколи</p>
                <p>1 пучок укропа</p>
                <p>Соль, перец по вкусу</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-right">
            <p>1. Филе индейки вымыть, нарезать мелкими кусочками. Лук и морковь почистить и нарезать мелкими кубиками.</p>
            <p>2. Положить нарезанную индейку в чашу мультиварки, залить водой и включить программу «СУП» на 1 час.</p>
            <p>3. После завершения программы «СУП» вынуть индейку из бульона.</p>
            <p>4. Бульон процедить и снова залить в чашу мультиварки, посолить, добавить укроп.</p>
            <p>5. Брокколи разобрат на соцветия. Добавить в бульон индейку, промытый рис и мелко нарезанные лук и морковь. Включить программу «КРУПЫ» на 30 минут.</p>
            <p>6. После завершения программы добавить сливки, перемешать и поставить на программу «КРУПЫ» еще на 10 минут.</p>
            <div class="add-dish"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see its quite long one. The information div `.dish-info` got `display:none`
The problem is that scroller is taking into count the height of `.dish-info`, so there displays a biiig gap. How should i avoid that?

Comment: As a side note, please spell check your recipe.

Comment: Sorry im not good at english

Comment: Your recipe is in Russian.

Comment: Yes it is, its just a text, why u need english one?

Comment: Anyway, to get back to the question... how does Nanoscroller determine the height of `.dish-info`? Does the div have an explicit `height` property in the stylesheet? The calculated height of display:none items is supposed to be zero.

Comment: Yes it should be zero, but the gap height is same as .dish-info is. When im inspecting that element it shows nothing.

Comment: Well, $('.dish-info').hide() was after initialize of scroller, now it is ok, but when i display the div, the scroll dont work anymore, there is no scroll pane